# How to use Asynchronous and onPostExecute to send value to PHP and get Response

Tags: java, android

How to send value to php page using **Asynchronous** with **HttpRequest** and get a response, then do something with it using **OnPostExcute** for example.

**Java** :

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Do something with the response here
        // ....
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("__url_to_file.php");

        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    }

}
```

**PHP** :

```
<?php
    // return the value back to the app
    echo $_POST["myHttpData"];

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, HttpResponse, HttpResponse>{

        @Override
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return postData(params[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result){
            View pb;
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            HttpEntity entity = result.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public HttpResponse postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("__url_to_file.php");

            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity((List<? extends org.apache.http.NameValuePair>) nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            return response;
        }

    }
```

You could do something with the above. That would certainly pass the HttpResponse to the onPostExecute method and allow you to do something with it.

I'd take a look at this line, though:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity((List<? extends org.apache.http.NameValuePair>) nameValuePairs));
```

As it didn't seem right to me. I had to add the cast to make the compiler happy. That may not be the desired result (but the point wast to get the ASyncTask to allow for processing the HttpResponse).

Comment: Accepted your answer, Thanks alot for your help :)